# How to copy multiple different cells to another worksheet in just one press of button

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, copy, transpose

How do you copy multiple different cells in another worksheet, my code for determining the range is shown below. It works fine if its just a range of cells but I want to include a cell that is cell "E6" and "J31" to another worksheet in order.

So the order goes like this cells J10 to J30 + E6 + J31.

My data is copied to another worksheet and is transposed so I want to copy it in order. Please help.

```
With Adjustments

Set copyRange = .Range("J10:J30") 'I want to add cells "E6" and "J31" here in the copyRange range but I always get the error mismatch.

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve this, the easiest (though not the quickest) is to use `Union(` as follows:

```
Set copyrange = Union(Sheet1.Range("A1:A2"), Sheet1.Range("A4:A5"), Sheet1.Range("E1"))
For Each cel In copyrange
    cel.Copy
    Range("B" & (Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Next cel
```

The issue with this is that you cannot copy it in one go, since you have multiple selections and copy doesn't work on that. So the way around that is to have a loop and copy every cell separately. This isn't the quickest, but the only solution if you need more than just the cells value to be copied over.

Another way to do it is to read your values into an array, and pasting the array in one go. This is significantly quicker, but cannot pull more from your cell than the values.

```
Set copyrange = Union(Sheet1.Range("A1:A2"), Sheet1.Range("A4:A5"), Sheet1.Range("E1"))
ReDim arr(0 To copyrange.Cells.Count)
For Each cel In copyrange
    arr(i) = cel.Value
    i = i + 1
Next cel
Range("B1:B" & i) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)
End Sub
```

Comment: Alternatively instead of `Union` you can also use `Sheet1.Range("A1:A2,A4:A5,E1")` if you hard code the addresses. Note that the address has a limit of 255 characters, if it is longer you will have to use `Union`.

Comment: Damn i tried this awhile ago but its Sheet1.Range("J10:30") And .Range("E6") like that thank you so much!!

Comment: I take that back hahaha it says that the command cannot be used on multiple selections, any ideas why?

Comment: You most likely have a copy action or anything of the sort going on the entire range in one go. As stated, this can't be done, you will have to handle every cell separately in a loop. This means you might have to rewrite your transpose function as well.